# How to parse a text file with hex codes?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I'm trying to write my first parsing script for this file;

```
;$FILEVERSION=1.3
;$STARTTIME=44512.7163933106
;
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Bus  Name         Connection          Protocol  Bit rate
;   1    Connection1  Untitled6@_usb      CAN       250 kbit/s
;   2    Connection2  Untitled5@_usb      CAN       500 kbit/s
;   3    Connection3  Untitled1@_usb      J1939     500 kbit/s
;   4    Connection4  Untitled2@_usb      CAN       250 kbit/s
;   5    Connection5  Untitled3@_usb      CAN       250 kbit/s
;   6    Connection6  Untitled7@_usb      J1939     250 kbit/s
;   7    Connection7  Single@_usb         CAN       250 kbit/s
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;   Message Number
;   |         Time Offset (ms)
;   |         |       Bus
;   |         |       |    Type
;   |         |       |    |       ID (hex)
;   |         |       |    |       |    Reserved
;   |         |       |    |       |    |   Data Length Code
;   |         |       |    |       |    |   |    Data Bytes (hex) ...
;   |         |       |    |       |    |   |    |
;   |         |       |    |       |    |   |    |
;---+-- ------+------ +- --+-- ----+--- +- -+-- -+ -- -- -- -- -- -- --
     1)         0.015 7  Rx        047A -  6    88 13 AD 92 11 00 
     2)         0.093 5  Rx    18FF6221 -  8    C0 F0 00 0C C0 FF 05 FF 
     3)         0.318 4  Rx        01FB -  8    02 30 00 C0 00 00 00 80 
     4)         0.484 7  Rx        02FA -  8    88 13 88 13 00 88 13 01
```

The file is logged data from a vehicle over CAN, I'm trying to read this using python to save me having to use another application that is slow and outdated.

How can I read this into python in a way that pandas can work with the data?

I'm new to python and newer to parsing files, any direction is really appreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file has fixed column length, use [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
widths = [8, 14, 3, 6, 9, 3, 5, 9999]
names = ['Message Number', 'Time Offset (ms)', 'Bus', 'Type', 'ID (hex)',
         'Reserved', 'Data Length Code', 'Data Bytes (hex)']

df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', index_col=None, comment=';',
                 header=None, widths=widths, names=names)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

  Message Number  Time Offset (ms)  Bus Type  ID (hex) Reserved  Data Length Code         Data Bytes (hex)
0             1)             0.015    7   Rx      047A        -                 6        88 13 AD 92 11 00
1             2)             0.093    5   Rx  18FF6221        -                 8  C0 F0 00 0C C0 FF 05 FF
2             3)             0.318    4   Rx      01FB        -                 8  02 30 00 C0 00 00 00 80
3             4)             0.484    7   Rx      02FA        -                 8  88 13 88 13 00 88 13 01
```